# Convert old SQL Database in compatibility mode

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have some old database exports (mdf + ldf) from the year 2006. 
I cannot attach them to SQL Server 2016 but to SQL Server 2008R2, then do a backup and restore it at SQL Server 2016. By this approach, the database files are converted.

My question is: Instead using SQL Server 2008R2 installation which is defined to be a security risk by my customer, I installed a second SQL Server 2016 instance and switched this to compatibility level 2008 to create the backup which is in turn restored then at the "real" SQL Server 2016.
Unfortunately, when I do the restore I get the error message

> "sql ... cannot be upgraded because its non release version is not
>   supported..."

So, if I understand correctly, this means that SQL Server 2016 with compatibility level 2008 is NOT the same as SQL Server 2008 installation itself. Is that correct?

What is the difference then? Is compatbility level only affecting SQL queries or the whole behaviour of the database (backup, restore etc.) ?

Comment: SQL Server 2008R2 isn't just a security risk, it's unsupported for quite some time now, and 10 years old. There are *huge* improvements in 2016+. Many enterprise features became available even in SQL Server Express with 2016 SP1. Never mind the completely different availability methods. Back in 2005 database mirroring was still v1, with quite a few issues

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, if I understand correctly, this means that SQL Server 2016 with compatibility level 
>   2008 is NOT the same as SQL Server 2008 installation itself. Is that correct?

Yes. Compatibility mode does not change the DB - it only changes the behavior of the database engine in certain aspects to make old applications still run as expected.

I.e. old compatibility levels will not accept certain new SQL constructs and show similar query behavior in times.

You have to install 2008R2 - and then bill the client for upgrading all the db exports ;)

Comment: I've got a related issue. I need to process transaction logs from SQL 2016, but have them end up on SQL 2019. Guess I need an intermediate installation of 2016 to process the logs, then copy the data out to 2019.

Comment: @theBenB post a different question then. Even better, post (or search) in `dba.stackexchange.com`. SO is for programming questions, the DBA-specific site is `dba.stackexchange.com`

Comment: @theBenB as for your specific question, did you try anything or read the docs? 2014 is still in extended support. I restored a SQL Server 2014 DB on SQL Server 2019 a week ago. 2005 on the other hand is *completely* unsupported for many years now.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was thinking out loud rather than asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

No Compatibility Levels and Version are *not* the same.

A database that is attached to an instance uses the same version of that of the instance. If that database was Restored from an older Instance (say SQL Server 2008) then the database will be upgraded during the `RESTORE` and then put in the appropriate Compatibility mode; this means that the database *acts* like it is on an older instance, however, it has still been upgraded.

You can only `RESTORE` a database to an instance which supports the compatibility level of the database. If your file is from 2006 the **latest** version that can be is 2005, which completely lost support in 2015. The latest version to support backups from SQL Server 2005 is SQL Server 2014; you **cannot** restore a 2005 backup or prior to SQL Server 2016.

If your backup is even older, you will have to use an even older version of SQL Server. If, for example, it is a SQL Server 2000 back up , you will **have** to obtain the unsupported SQL Server 2008, `RESTORE` the database, increase the compatibility level to 90 (2008), `BACKUP` the database, and then `RESTORE` it on a supported version.